# showModelessDialog opens the document in ie8 mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, hta, showmodaldialog

Open the HTML dialog from the HTA application using showModelessDialog/showModalDialog. The HTA application is running in mode ie11 (tag `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">`), but the dialog opened always runs in mode ie8. The tag `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">` in the opened document does not work.
How to open a document using showModelessDialog/showModalDialog in the mode ie11? This is needed for svg or WebGL in the dialog.

Main.hta:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="showModelessDialog ('Dialog.hta'); return false;">Open Dialog</a>  
    </body>
    <script>
        alert (navigator.userAgent);
    </script>
</html>
```

Dialog.hta

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">   
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert (navigator.userAgent);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: iirc, since showModalDialog was deprecated before IE10, they froze it's mode as IE8.

Comment: @dandavis Modal dialogs work on HTML pages very well in IE9, IE10 and IE11 standards mode, they were "frozen" in htas only. I've [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11727815/1169519) about this a couple of years ago ...

Comment: I tried to use IHostDialogHelper->ShowHTMLDialog result in the same - maximally ie8. Meta and FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION did not solve the problem.

Comment: It can't be solved, Microsoft has dropped support for HTAs for years ago. Diaologs were not updated for IE9 anymore, and there's no way to get a support for modern standards of dialogs. The only way is either to use regular windows as dialogs, or you can implement your own dialog system using iframes and/or separate HTA files. A third option is to emulate dialogs with divs like modern web apps are doing.

Comment: Well thank you. Very sorry. A good opportunity to create simple multi-windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by creating a COM object with two functions SetObject and GetObject. The object is sent using the WM_GETOBJECT message as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425770/in-proc-com-object-sharing-across-another-process).